# Cannot resolve symbol 'println' in intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, sdk

I cannot seem to get rid of "cannot resolve println symbol in intellij", what i have tried:-

1. check the appropriate sdk(14.0.1 jdk) under project structure.
   2)include the same jdk under modules too and added it to home path
   3)included java version 14.0.1 in pom.xml file also.

Below are the screenshots:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit:- I got worked up only to find myself being caught in an error caused due to a closing brace.
Also thanks whoever tried to help!

Comment: Also consider that you might have a problem just before the `println`, and that is throwing the compiler off.  Happens sometimes, but check everything besides the `println` too.  If you can't see it, remove lines by commenting them out, until the problem goes away.  Then you know the last line you commented had a problem.

Comment: @CrazyCoder did that to, didn't work!

Comment: @markspace i just have a println, nothing else and the error appears on println only, "System" didn't appear as a red highlight

Comment: Please post your code as text rather than as an image.

Comment: Thanks guys, just found the error. wasn't  related to jdk, but a simple closing brace was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have the method call directly inside the class body, not inside the main method as your main method body is already closed with `}`.

You may want to disable IDE code folding to avoid such problems in the future:

Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Code Folding | One-line methods.